# Notify user when insert operation is successful

Tags: c#, asp.net, insert, objectdatasource, detailsview

I'm developing asp net application that allows to insert a record using object data source and details view. I'm wondering if there any way to inform a user (e.g. pop out message) that a record was successfully added? E.g. something similar to that but with insert (which event should I use)?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkBtnDelete" runat="server" 
OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want delete?')) return false;" 
CommandName="Delete">Delete 
</asp:LinkButton>
```

My code for insert:

```
public static void InsertPatient(PatientBLL patient)
    {
         string ins = "INSERT INTO Patients (PPS,Surname,Name, DOB,Gender,BloodGroup,MedicalCard,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,City,County,Phone,Mobile,Email) VALUES(@PPS,@Surname,@Name,@DOB,@Gender,@BloodGroup,@MedicalCard,@AddressLine1,@AddressLine2,@City,@County,@Phone,@Mobile,@Email)";
         using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
         {
             using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ins, con))
             {
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PPS", patient.PPS);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Surname", patient.Surname);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", patient.Name);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DOB", patient.DOB);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Gender", patient.Gender);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("BloodGroup", patient.BloodGroup ?? Convert.DBNull);  // if textbox is left empty, use null as column value
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MedicalCard", patient.MedicalCard  ); // ?? Convert.DBNull
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("AddressLine1", patient.AddressLine1);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("AddressLine2", patient.AddressLine2 ?? Convert.DBNull);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("City", patient.City);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("County", patient.County);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Phone", patient.Phone ?? Convert.DBNull);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Mobile", patient.Mobile ?? Convert.DBNull);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", patient.Email ?? Convert.DBNull);

                 con.Open();
                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteNonQuery()` returns the total number of rows updated , so you use th return value and display the message to notify the user.

From MSDN: [`ExecuteNonQuery()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and **returns
>   the number of rows affected.**

```
int status = 0;
status = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    
string script = "alert(\"Rows Inserted Successfully!\");";

 if(status > 0)
 { 
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), 
                      "ServerControlScript", script, true);
 }
```

Comment: thanks but when I put it into the method I got errors on ScriptManager line: keyword this is not valid in a static method and I need object reference with GetType() method

Answer (score 0):

The common approach:

```
int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The result is 1 (number of affected rows) if the insert operation is successful.